# Поиск по dataGridView C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать поиск по двум столбцам грида? У меня реализован поиск через фильтр, но ищет только по одному столбцу, вот код:

```
DataTable booksTable = katDataSet.Tables["books"];
            DataView dv = new DataView(booksTable);
            dv.RowFilter = " author LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Просьба помочь!

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте, (OR/AND) в зависимости чего хотите получить....

```
dv.RowFilter = " author LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR  bookname LIKE '%" + bookName.Text + "%'";
```